# How to fetch all data from 2 tables and display all not working

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I'm trying to fetch data from an items table and an inventory table and display the information. The problem I'm having is everything is displayed right except it only displays whats in my inventory table, and I would like it to display all items from the items table and quantity from my inventory table. How would I do this correctly here is my code

```
$result= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory ON inventory.itemid=items.id WHERE inventory.userid = '".$userid."'");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {



    if ($row['type'] == 0 && $row['level'] > 0){
        $item .= "

        <td width='200px'>
            <form action='gear.php' method='post'>
                <div class='featured_items'><img src='". $row['image']."' width='80' height='80' style='border: 1px solid #333'></div>
                <div class='featured_items_info'>". $row['itemname'] ." <br />
                    Att ". $row['attack'] ."
                    | Def ". $row['defense'] ."<br />
                    Cost ". $row['cost'] ."<br />
                    Own ". $row['quantity'] ."<br />



                <input type='hidden' name='gear_id' value='". $row['id'] ."' />
                <input type='submit' value='Buy' />
            </form>

        </td>

        "; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the given user has any rows in the inventory table?

Comment: First of all, forget about mysqli_* functions, move to PDO. Anyway, your SQL code looks correct, please check your query in SQL prompt (do you have rows for userID?), maybe you have incorrect columns in query.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Thats my issue if a user doest have a item in the table it will not display. Im trying to display all available items to purchase even if a user doesn't have that item, and if the user does have that item it will display the quantity of that item

Answer (score 0):

The left join didn't work the way you intended because you used the `user_id` field, which belonged to `inventory`. Moving the condition to `on` will fix it:

```
SELECT id, type, level, image, itemname, attack, defense, 
    cost, coalesce(inventory.quantity, 0) quantity
FROM items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory ON inventory.itemid=items.id and inventory.userid = '".$userid."'"
```

Just make sure you use `coalesce` in `select` to handle items that user doesn't have.

Comment: Thank you Fabricator, this fixed my issue, the only thing now is the userid isnt  being inserted into the data base since the code has been changed